# How to make a grid from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've searched the site for other questions about how to do this, but I haven't found any close enough to figure it out. I've read the python documentation on dictionaries, and still am confused. I know it's basic but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I have a dictionary with (x,y) tuples for keys and want to make a grid from this dictionary. I want each (x,y) coordinate in the grid to be represented by a '.' so I would ultimately have a grid of dots that I could later edit to be other symbols.

This is what I tried:

```
def createEmptyGrid(grid_dimensions):
    grid = {}
    for x in range(grid_dimensions):
        for y in range(grid_dimensions):
            grid[x,y] = '.'
    return grid

def initial_grid(cell_dimensions, density, disease):
    grid = createEmptyGrid(cell_dimensions)
    for cell in grid:
        print grid[cell]


print initial_grid(3, 0, 0)
```

my output is:

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
None
```

I get why it is giving me this output, because I am telling it to just print every value in the dictionary, but I just don't know how to modify it do do what I want.

My expected output is:

```
 . . .
 . . .
 . . .
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for cell in grid:
    print grid[cell]
```

This says "for each cell in the grid, print it's value *on a new line*". The final `None` is from this line

```
print initial_grid(3, 0, 0)
```

As the function `initial_grid` has no return value, so it is printing `None`.

A python dict is not a very efficient way of storing values in a grid formation, but if you'd like to print it, try something like:

```
def createEmptyGrid(grid_dimensions):
    grid = {}
    for x in range(grid_dimensions):
        for y in range(grid_dimensions):
            grid[x,y] = '.'
    return grid

def initial_grid(cell_dimensions, density, disease):
    grid = createEmptyGrid(cell_dimensions)
    return grid

def print_grid(grid, cell_dimensions):
    for y in range(cell_dimensions):
        for x in range(cell_dimensions):
            print grid[x,y], # note the comma
        print '' # start a new line after each row


grid = initial_grid(3, 0, 0)
print_grid(grid, 3)
```

Comment: So the comma indicates that you want things to be printed on the same line?

Comment: Yes, assuming you're using python 2.x

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use 2D list instead of dict. Maybe:

```
def createEmptyGrid(grid_dimensions):
    grid = [None] * grid_dimensions
    for x in range(grid_dimensions):
        grid[x] = ['.'] * grid_dimensions
    return grid

def initial_grid(cell_dimensions, density, disease):
    grid = createEmptyGrid(cell_dimensions)
    for cell in grid:
        print ' '.join(cell)

initial_grid(3, 0, 0)
```

Runable code: https://ideone.com/94P6ZM

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of the dimensions of the grid while printing, so that you can print a row at a time:

```
def createEmptyGrid(grid_dimensions):
    grid = {}
    for x in range(grid_dimensions):
        for y in range(grid_dimensions):
            grid[x,y] = '.'
    return grid

def initial_grid(cell_dimensions, density, disease):
    grid = createEmptyGrid(cell_dimensions)
    for y in range(cell_dimensions):
        print(' '.join(grid[x, y] for x in range(cell_dimensions)))

# Don't need to print this call as the function already
# prints
initial_grid(3, 0, 0)
```

That means that you'll need to keep track of the dimensions as you use the grid in other functions. I guess you could also scan the dictionary every time you wanted to print to
reconstruct the dimensions,
which would look something like this:

```
n_rows = max(y for x, y in g.keys())
n_cols = max(x for x, y in g.keys())
```

but that would be a bit of a cumbersome solution.

Comment: You should probably be iterating over `y` first when printing the grid, as it stands you're printing it sideways.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you mind giving me a brief explanation of the formatting of this line: print(' '.join(grid[x, y] for y in range(cell_dimensions))) I've never used that horizontal format for a for loop, does it serve the exact same purpose? is there an equivalent way to rewrite it vertically?

Comment: That form of for loop is called a "list comprehension". I'm not sure if I can give a quick explanation that will do justice to it, but they're quite common in Python code and very useful once you've got the hang of them. The vertical equivalent is basically the way Peter Gibson did it, where he adds a comma after the value to prevent `print` moving to a new line.